# Product price changed to 0.00 in product detail page

Tags: javascript, magento, magento2

I am facing a very strange issue after the installation of Magento 2.0.4. I have create a product with the price $12 and change the locale from Magento configuration in backend.

Below is the screenshot for the listing page.

[image]

Also find the below screenshot for the detail page.

[image]

You might have noticed the difference between two screenshot. Yes, Product detail page shows $0.00 price while listing page has retain with the price what i have added.

Product details page automatically updates correct price to $0,00 after one or two seconds (JavaScript Updates).

Find the below code for it

```
$('[data-price-type="' + priceCode + '"]', this.element).html(priceTemplate({data: price}));
```

I have debug further in the code and found another JavaScript code that passes parameter to Magento 2 pricebox widget.

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box'
    ], function($){
        var priceBoxes = $('[data-role=priceBox]');

        priceBoxes = priceBoxes.filter(function(index, elem){
            return !$(elem).find('.price-from').length;
        });

        priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonConfig() ?>});
    });
</script>
```

Now I have checked the getJsonConfig() method,

```
  $product = $this->getProduct();

        if (!$this->hasOptions()) {
            $config = [
                'productId' => $product->getId(),
                'priceFormat' => $this->_localeFormat->getPriceFormat()
                ];
            return $this->_jsonEncoder->encode($config);
        }

        $tierPrices = [];
        $tierPricesList = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('tier_price')->getTierPriceList();
        foreach ($tierPricesList as $tierPrice) {
            $tierPrices[] = $this->priceCurrency->convert($tierPrice['price']->getValue());
        }
        $config = [
            'productId' => $product->getId(),
            'priceFormat' => $this->_localeFormat->getPriceFormat(),
            'prices' => [
                'oldPrice' => [
                    'amount' => $this->priceCurrency->convert(
                        $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getAmount()->getValue()
                    ),
                    'adjustments' => []
                ],
                'basePrice' => [
                    'amount' => $this->priceCurrency->convert(
                        $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getBaseAmount()
                    ),
                    'adjustments' => []
                ],
                'finalPrice' => [
                    'amount' => $this->priceCurrency->convert(
                        $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getValue()
                    ),
                    'adjustments' => []
                ]
            ],
            'idSuffix' => '_clone',
            'tierPrices' => $tierPrices
        ];
```

I did lot of debugging through the code and come to the conclusion that they are using ICUDATA for locale support.

I am stuck with this all thing, It seems it is PriceFormat issue.

Comment: Check this function "getPrice(" in this file "Magento\Catalog\Model\Product.php". Even when debugging shows $0 price add more details